# Online web development. Swap between develop and production version

Tags: git, version-control, versioning

We have a problem in your developer team. We are making a website and we do it online right in ftp. For develop we use developer.subdomain.com and if everything is ok, we transfer it to domain.com. But it is so ineffective! Transfer of whole website takes hours.

I google a lot and i found the Git. We try it a bit but as i understand, git is better if you develop offline and only upload your revisions.

Maybe i understand that is better to develop offline but we have a team of developers in home offices and everybody needs to see work of other team mates.
So we need to be online.

Is there something how to develop online and have some versioning system?

EDITED: IS there any solution how to develop website right on ftp (not offline development) and not have to copy all files from develop folder to product folder manually and change all databases etc. ?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but I recommend using Git in general for most web development.  If you clean up your question I can give you a more focused answer.

Comment: i edit my question. Hope is a bit clearer

Comment: If you use Git you would be working with (relatively) light weight _branches_.  You won't have to copy your entire project as you move through each stage of the development process.  Instead, you would be doing branching operations like `merge` and `rebase`.